# What should the dockerfile for a kotline project look like for AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kotlin, gradle, aws-lambda

I'm deploying some Kotlin code via a container and running it via AWS Lambda. However, I keep running into an issue where when I invoke the Lambda, it cannot find the main class or handler.

This is what my Dockefile look like currently

```
# This builder image will not be used at runtime
# See https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/
FROM gradle:6.7.1 as builder

# Copy sourcecode into build image
COPY app/build.gradle ./app/
COPY app/src/ ./app/src/
COPY settings.gradle ./
COPY gradle.properties ./
COPY entrypoint.sh ./


ENV ARTIFACTORY_CREDENTIALS_USR=njohnson
ENV ARTIFACTORY_CREDENTIALS_PSW=[redacted]

RUN gradle clean build --no-daemon --stacktrace

# Now switch to the runtime image; base it on the latest Java, in a "slim" variant.
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk13:debianslim-jre
# Put the one necessary class files, with all dependencies, into the into the runtime.


CMD ["java", "-jar", "./app.jar"]
CMD ["readCartMessageDBLambda.Handler::handler"]
```

This is a small snippet from my build.gradle file

```
application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'readCartMessageDBLambda.Handlerkt'
}
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/kotlin']




jar {
    zip64 true
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': application.mainClass
    }
    from {
        configurations.compileClasspath.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the proper format for the dockerfile or am I missing something? Currently I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class readCartMessageDBLambda.Handlerkt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: readCartMessageDBLambda.Handlerkt
```

I've been unable to find a lot of examples for Kotlin w/ AWS Lambda and Docker so I'm hoping someone can help me.

Comment: One aspect that looks suspicious to me is the name of the class: `Handlerkt`. Usually Kotlin compiler will generate classes with capital K: `HandlerKt`. Could you run `gradle` locally and check what is the name of the generated class in the `target` directory?

Comment: A dockerfile can't have multiple `CMD`. I think it just takes the last one in the file.

Comment: I suggest following the guide for Java Lambda containers https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-image.html, including using the base Java Lambda image (see the Usage tab) https://gallery.ecr.aws/lambda/java

Comment: @AlexeySoshin Hey, so I changed the lowercase to a capital 'K' in `HandlerKt` and I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: @MarkB Okay, I removed the first `CMD` so that it's just `CMD ["readCartMessageDBLambda.Handler::handler"]` Still same issue. I've looked at both of the links you've sent already. The issue is that it seems that a lot of the build dependencies are coming from the `build/dependency/*` directory and my project directory doesn't have anything like that. I'm think that's a different between Java and Kotlin?

Comment: It's saying it can't find your handler class, which should be in your main jar file. So I don't see how dependencies are related to the error.